# Meaning of "lag" in "lag bolt"

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

From [this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/143913/21559) answer:

> The screws (actually called "**lag bolts**") bite into the wood immediately around them, and the wood fibers around that hold the bolt in place.

I looked up the [meaning](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lag+bolt) of "lag bolt", and it's

> a heavy woodscrew with a square or hexagonal head that is driven in with a wrench

Why is it a "lag" bolt? What is the meaning of "lag" here? I've read [all meanings](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lag#English) at Wiktionary to no avail. Does it somehow relate to the meaning of "delay"?

Comment: For what it's worth, even most native English speakers have no idea why they're called *lag bolts* and never give it much thought!

Comment: @stangdon - you mean it is not worth asking?

Comment: @user070221 - I don't mean it is not worth asking, I just mean that it is a question most native speakers never even think about asking, and which they could not answer themselves.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lag bolts or screws derive their name from *lag meaning  stave.*  They were bolts typically used to fasten barrel staves.

Origin of "lag screw":

> First recorded in 1870–75
> ***Also called coach screw, [lag bolt](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lag-screw).***

Word origin according to Dictionary.com:

> from [lag ³;](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lag) ***the screw was originally used to fasten barrel staves.***
>
> - the insulating casing of a steam cylinder, boiler, etc; lagging
> - a stave or lath - from 1665–75; < Scandinavian; compare Swedish lagg stave

Comment: I feel like this could be a question on Final Jeopardy, topic *Esoteric word origins* :)

Comment: @Andrew -         I know users are allergic to etymology on this site, don’t know why, that’s why I asked here for it to be moved to a “safer” place: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4762/should-the-following-question-be-moved-to-elu

Comment: No, it's fine here.  I just mean that the etymology of some English words is ridiculously obscure but nevertheless interesting.  For example, *decoy* comes from 16th century Dutch word for a kind of duck trap, *de kooi* ("the cage").

Comment: @Andrew - well, unluckily not all word origins are clear, that’s the job of etymologists. I agree sometime assumptions look a bit..,stretched.

Answer (score -3):

It doesn't mean anything.  "Lag bolt" is a compound word, the meaning of which you know.

Lag bolts are not bolts (they don't through unthreaded holes) and they aren't "lag" in any of the standard meanings of lag.

Its etymology seems uncertain, but may be related to a Swedish word.

In compound words the individual parts may be recognisable (like bolt) or not. The meaning of the individual parts of a compound word may have been lost.

Comment: Fascinating, anything to support what you are saying?

Comment: For example  "killifish". It is a compound word "killi" and "fish"  I know what a fish is, but "killi" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Kill in kill(i)fish appears to derive from : ***kill***: channel, creek —used chiefly in place names in Delaware, Pennsylvania, and New York.

Comment: Perhaps, but it doesn't have currency as an independent word, which is my point.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, kill meaning channel/creek is an independent word,  the only issue here is about the reliability of this etymology.